# Android - Set Background Color not working

Tags: java, android, colors

I have and activity and I am setting the background color, and the status bar color, and even though I have setting them as the same thing, I see a different color?

I set the background color like this

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
        Log.i(TAG, colorMain + "");
        rl.setBackgroundColor(colorMain);
```

And the status bar color like this

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19)
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Log.i(TAG, colorMain + "");
            window.setStatusBarColor(colorMain);
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        }
```

Where colorMain is an int set above and as you can see I log the color before it is displayed and it logs the same for each color. I have been check if maybe I was overriding the color somewhere else in the code but Ive looked it over a bunch and can't find anything?

Basically, I set the color of the status bar and my background as the same thing, but when I run my app, I see different colors

Any one have any ideas whats going on?

Thanks for the help :)

**EDIT**

SO I set the background to the same color but as you can see the stars bar and background are different colors?

I have set the backgroud color as hex color #AF7828 and then tried #BE8728, but it shows the same color as the background? But if I set it to `Color.GREEN` it shows green? I am so confused?

[image]

Comment: Not understand your question....elaborate  more

Comment: I set the color of the status bar and my background as the same thing, but when I run my app, I see different colors @MD

Comment: to set the color mnRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of your problem? it will help to clear matters.

Comment: your code for changing status bar color will only work in SDK version 19 or above versions.In which sdk you ran code?

Comment: If you have anything inside your Relativelayout? If it is empty, it will not show your background.

Comment: the status bar color is the is set to the correct color I am running in API 21, and yes I have a list view in my relative layout. And its not that I don't see the color in the background, I see a shade of the color its supposed to be. See edit

Comment: you mean the top bar is a little darker than the background or second row right? perhaps android has like a darker color behind it? http://www.google.co.uk/design/spec/style/color.html#color-ui-color-application under Toolbars and status bar

Comment: @fersarr yes ignore the action bar color, but the background color should be the same as the status bar color (bar with time at very top). As they are set to the same color?